# MongoExport valid JSON query construction

Tags: json, mongodb, export

I'm trying to export a subset of my collection. I only want documents that contain a specific 'search' id. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong in defining my query though to isolate the relevant documents. This is what I am entering:

```
mongoexport --db data --collection user_admin --fieldFile exportfields.txt --query {'search':ObjectId("5621634716c878440a4e4aaf")} --type=csv --out user_admin.csv
```

This is the error that I receive:

> error validating settings: query
>   '{'search':ObjectId(5621634716c878440a4e4aaf)}' is not valid JSON:
>   invalid character 'c' after constructor argument

Thanks! :)

P.S. I am using Mongod v3.0.6

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the right order for the quotes in my JSON query given that I am running it via the Windows command prompt:

```
mongoexport --db data --collection user_admin --fieldFile exportfields.txt --query "{'search':ObjectId('5621634716c878440a4e4aaf')}" --type=csv --out user_admin.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

According tot the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/), you must enclose your query in single quotes. However, from experience this does not apply when using a Windows command prompt. If you use a DOS command prompt you need to enclose your query with double quotes, but replace every quote inside your query with a single quote.

So your query should like this if you are not using Windows DOS:

```
--query '{"search":ObjectId(5621634716c878440a4e4aaf)}'
```

Or like this when executing `mongoexport` from the command line:

```
--query "{'search':ObjectId(5621634716c878440a4e4aaf)}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm running it via the Windows command prompt so your second suggestion holds I think. When I use your second suggestion: `mongoexport --db data --collection user_admin --fieldFile exportfields.txt --query "{'search':ObjectId(5621634716c878440a4e4aaf)}" --type=csv --out user_admin.csv` I get this error: _"error validating settings: query '{'search':ObjectId(5621634716c878440a4e4aaf)}' is not valid JSON: invalid character 'c' after constructor argument"_ still.

Comment: Aha! I figured it out. The ObjectId value needed to be in single quotes as well. Thanks for your help :)